The inverse Laplace transform of s^(NS)Log[s]
I am currently investigating a problem related to random walks. The problem has been reduced to finding the inverse Laplace transform of the following function:
$$\int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty}\exp(s\cdot t)s^{N\cdot s}\log(s)ds$$
where
$s$ is the Laplace variable corresponding to $t$, i.e., the Laplace transform of a given function $f(t)$ follows $\widehat{f}(s)=\int_0^\infty\exp(-st)f(t)dt$. I attempted to use a Taylor expansion to address this, but it did not yield any useful results.
I would appreciate any suggestions or insights regarding approaches to tackle this problem. The method related to the asymptotic behavior is also welceome. Thank you!

As it is written, the Laplace transform is, in the tempered distributions sense, equal to $s^{Ns}\log(s)\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\mathrm{e}^{s(c+\mathrm{i}u)}(\mathrm{i}\mathrm{d}u)=\mathrm{i}s^{Ns}\log(s)\mathrm{e}^{cs}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}su}\mathrm{d}u=2\pi \mathrm{i}s^{Ns}\log(s)\mathrm{e}^{cs}\delta(s)$.

@Nicolas   Sorry,  I make a mistake. The intrgral is related to $s$.

Could you please confirm the exponent of $s$ in the integrand: is it $s^{N\cdot s}$?

@Nicolas   The formula your writen is correct.  It is $s^{N\times s}$.

The $s$ term in the power is very troublesome. It is not clear which sense this integral converges in: $s^{s}$ is not a tempered distribution, so unless you are working with some nice analytic classes of test functions, I do not see how to deal with this Laplace transform... Could you provide some background?

@Nicolas   Thanks for your time consider this problem.  The backgrond is related to the renewal process. To be more exactly,  in Laplace space, the PDF of number of renewals follows $s^{Ns}log[s]$ with $s\to 0$. Here $s\to0$ means that the observation time $t$ tends to $\infty$.  The $N$ denotes the number of the renewals at the time $t$.
